# Bounty expired, and no answers -- now what?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, bounty

I put a bounty on [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/16474/why-is-my-ender-3-restarting-spontaneously-in-mid-print), because the one answer it had seemed as if the answerer hadn't read the (admittedly long) question.

The bounty just expired, and according to the message, I "must award it to an answer within 24 hours."

Only problem is, there are no answers (the one that was there when I raised the bounty has been deleted).  I don't have an answer of my own to self-answer, the problem I asked about is still unsolved.  How can I proceed in this case?

Comment: Great question.

Comment: I've had this happen when I put a bounty on somebody else's question. Sometimes there are just no answers, especially on very particular problems. :-( Note that the question itself is clear, the problem on the other hand is very difficult to grasp, I'm still inclined to put it in the category of a broken cable that sometimes loses connection or shorts as a result of the movement of the nozzle carriage, I've experienced that myself with a faulty BLTouch cable.

Comment: That doesn't seem to stop people trying to answer (and even getting votes from similarly clueless readers) on other SE sites...

Comment: I'll try to do an experiment early in a throw-away print -- I'll pull the extruder or z-axis stepper cable (those are fixed location and accessible while running) and see if that will stop the machine (effectively, simulating a broken wire disconnect).  Occurred to me this morning that since this happens while printing infill (as opposed to walls) about 90% of the time, it might well be movement induced, but could also be the microSD socket losing connection.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Indeed, bounties do attract attention, sometime the wrong kind... It is up to the community to vote the quality of the answer certainly when bounties are involved, you've seen that the deleted answer was such an answer but it got voted down. Hence voting is key, thank you for your contribution in that respect!

Comment: @ZeissIkon Beware that pulling live stepper cables can destroy stepper drivers, be sure to read some info in that respect!

Comment: Sigh.  So much for the easy way.  I already know (as a tool repair person) how annoying it is to try to trace an intermittent, and replacing the cables involves those woven wire looms...  :(

Comment: See SE.Meta; [bounty expired with no answers… wasted reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51286/280335)

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately the [Help Center](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) helps out:

> **How is a bounty awarded?**
>
> The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty. Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer. (You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)
>
> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). >If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.
>
> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.
>
> As a special bonus, any reputation you earn from being awarded a bounty is exempt from the daily reputation cap.

There has to be answer to award the bounty, in this particular case there aren't any answers, so no bounty can be rewarded. The messages you receive are the standard messages. You cannot select an answer, nor can the system. If the deleted answer hadn't been deleted, the negative score would have prevented from being selected by the system as it needs a 2+ vote for automatic rewarding.

Basically, you cannot do anything. You could consider removing (deleting) the question, this is a very particular / intermittent failure that is very difficult to troubleshoot. You might find the solution yourself one day!

Comment: I think I'm better leaving the question -- at least someone else with the same problem will know to call an exorcist first.  Will the system put up a message saying the bounty wasn't awarded, leave the bounty banner up, or just remove it entirely (along with my 50 rep)?

Comment: @ZeissIkon Unfortunately, bounties are non-refundable and immediately deduced from your reputation stack. I hope you once find the solution and post it yourself. The banner will be gone after the grace period has ended.

Comment: k.  If I find a solution, you may rest assured I'll post it.

Comment: The solution is, if you don't award the points, the points go away and nobody gets them. There is nothing stating you ***have*** to award the points. If there's nothing you can award the points to, then that's that. This is how the system works. I'm not sure what there would be to troubleshot.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The solution mentioned in comments hints to the solution of https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/16474/why-is-my-ender-3-restarting-spontaneously-in-mid-print not the solution of this question :-)